# Can we collect two lists from Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider I have a list with two types of data,one valid and the other invalid.

If I starting filter through this list, can i collect two lists at the end?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read on here to how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
Explain in detail about your question. What have you been tried so far? What do you mean by Invalid here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another suggestion: filter using a `lambda` that adds the elements that you want to filter out of the stream to a separate list.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also implemented the same solution.

Comment: This doesn't work well if you want to use parallel streams.

Answer (score 9):

> Can we collect two lists from Java 8 streams?

You cannot but if you have a way to group elements of the `List`s according to a  condition.
In this case you could for example use `Collectors.groupingBy()` that will return `Map<Foo, List<Bar>>` where the values of the `Map` are the two List.

Note that in your case you don't need stream to do only filter.

Filter the invalid list with `removeIf()` and add all element of that in the first list :

```
invalidList.removeIf(o -> conditionToRemove);
goodList.addAll(invalidList);
```

If you don't want to change the state of `goodList` you can do a shallow copy of that :

```
invalidList.removeIf(o -> conditionToRemove);
List<Foo> terminalList = new ArrayList<>(goodList);
terminalList.addAll(invalidList);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a way using Java 8 streams API. Consider I have a `List` of `String` elements: the input list has strings with various lengths; only strings with length 3 are valid.

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = input.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.length() == 3));
System.out.println(map); // {false=[three, four, five], true=[one, two]}
```

The resulting `Map` has *only* two records; one with valid and the other with not-valid input list elements. The map record with *key=true* has the valid string as a `List`: one, two. The other is a *key=false* and the not-valid strings: three, four, five.

Note the `Collectors.partitioningBy` produces always two records in the resulting map irrespective of the existence of valid or not-valid values.

Comment: Second code line must used stream method to compile:
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = input.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.length() == 3));

Comment: @MartinP. You are correct - I had not noticed it.  Thanks for pointing. May be I was thinking about something like `input = Stream.of("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")`, and typed something else ://3

Answer (score 2):

The collector can only return a single object!

But you could create a custom collector that simply puts the stream elements into two lists, to then return a list of lists containing these two lists.

There are many [examples](http://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-07-java-8-creating-a-custom-collector-for-your-stream/) how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the link of creating custom collector

Answer (score 1):

If you need to classify binary (true|false), you can use [Collectors.partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) that will return *Map<Boolean, List>* (or other downstream collection like Set, if you additionally specify).

If you need more than 2 categories - use *groupBy* or just *Collectors.toMap* of collections.